# How can I make my h2 database persistent in micronaut like I do in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, h2, micronaut

I'm somewhat familiar with grails and gorm and I try to make my first steps in micronaut.
I'm successful in storing my Person Entity with Person.save() and retrieve with Person.findAll() in an in Memory H2-Database. But I'm not successful in storing my Person persistently on my disk. My micronaut-cli.yml looks like that:

```html
profile: service
defaultPackage: my.app
---
testFramework: spock
sourceLanguage: groovy
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    #url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
    url: jdbc:h2:file:/home/peter/devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    dbCreate: create
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

As you see I commented out the in memory url and replaced it by a file url. With that url I expected a devDb.h2.db dataset in my home directory as I know it from my grails environment.

What's the difference between hibernate/gorm in grails and hibernate/gorm outside grails ?

Answer (score 0):

You have put your dataSource config in `micronaut-cli.yml`.  Instead you want to put that in `src/main/resources/application.yml` (or wherever you are expressing your application's runtime config, which `micronaut-cli.yml` is not).

I hope that helps.

Comment: It helped a lot, now the database is persistent where it belongs, thank you for your immediate answer.